# How to forward declare a C++ struct in case nested namespaces are used?

Tags: c++, nested, namespaces, forward-declaration

I have following C++ code

A.h

```
namespace x {
namespace y {
namespace z {
   
struct Container;

class A
{
public:
    A(Container& _container);
    
    void info();
    
private:
    Container& container;
};

}
}
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace x {
namespace y {
namespace z {

A::A(Container& _container) : container(_container) {}

void A::info() {
    std::cout << "Instance of A!" << std::endl;
}

}
}
}
```

Container.h

```
#include "A.h"

namespace x {
namespace y {
namespace z {

struct Container {

    Container(): a(*this) {}
    A a;
};

}
}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Container.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    x::y::z::Container container;
    
    container.a.info();

    return 0;
}
```

The above mentioned code is compilable and workable.

But let's say I move the `Container.h` out of the `z` `namespace` and let it in the `y` `namespace` (nested in the `x` `namespace`). So the code will look like that

A.h

```
namespace x {
namespace y {
namespace z {
   
struct Container;

class A
{
public:
    A(x::y::Container& _container);
    
    void info();
    
private:
    x::y::Container& container;
};

}
}
}
```

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace x {
namespace y {
namespace z {

A::A(x::y::Container& _container) : container(_container) {}

void A::info() {
    std::cout << "Instance of A!" << std::endl;
}

}
}
}
```

Container.h

```
#include "A.h"

namespace x {
namespace y {

struct Container {

    Container(): a(*this) {}
    x::y::z::A a;
};

}
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include "Container.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    
    x::y::Container container;
    
    container.a.info();

    return 0;
}
```

In that case the compilation fails with following error messages:

```
In file included from A.cpp:7:
A.h:26:22: error: expected ')' before '&' token
   26 |     A(x::y::Container& _container);
      |      ~               ^
      |                      )
A.h:31:11: error: 'Container' in namespace 'x::y' does not name a type
   31 |     x::y::Container& container;
      |           ^~~~~~~~~
A.cpp:14:5: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token
   14 | A::A(x::y::Container& _container) : container(_container)
      |     ^
```

Can anybody tell me why these error messages pop up in case I move the `Container.h` from the `z` `namespace` and let it in the `y` `namespace` nested in the `x` `namespace`?

Comment: Your forward declaration in `A.h` is still for a struct `x::y::z::Container`. Try moving that to `x::y` instead of `x::y::z` analogous to the move you made in `Container.h`.

Comment: fwiw, this is a minimal example of the same issue: https://godbolt.org/z/arWE7P

Comment: At the point of usage in `A` the compiler has not seen a declaration of `x::y::Container` only a forward declaration for one nested one level deeper inside z `x::y::z::Container` thus you are getting errors about not seeing `Container` as a type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you never declared `x::y::Container` in A.h. You did declare `x::y::z::Container`, but that doesn't name the same type. Simply move the declaration into the `y` namespace:

> ```
> namespace y {
> namespace z {
>    
> struct Container;
> ```

Into ->

```
namespace y {

struct Container;

namespace z {
```